# Python Selenium Linux Headless Issue

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, screen-scraping, headless

I have been stuck for many days with a problem that does not allow me to advance my project. I'm trying to scrape onlyfans (obviously information that is available for free, such as profile photo, biography information), the problem is that I can't do it with some, even though the selectors are the same for all profiles.

I simplified the code to try to get only one thing and it still works with some profiles and not with others, I don't understand why. Try different browsers, and also implement that it takes a screenshot and it shows that the profile you are trying to access is invalid, which is not the case. Try all possible selector types. The only thing that works is to run the code in a Windows environment with an interface but my server is on Linux (digital ocean droplet) with only a console so it is not a solution for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service  

# Function to get Chrome service
def get_chrome_service():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless=new")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
    chrome_binary_path = "/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver"
    chrome_service = Service(chrome_binary_path)

    return chrome_service, chrome_options

# Get Chrome service
chrome_service, chrome_options = get_chrome_service()

driver = None

try:
    # Initialize WebDriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=chrome_options)
    
    #url = "https://onlyfans.com/eireenskinnygirl"  #this profile works fine
    url = "https://onlyfans.com/mayukoxo"           #this one not
    driver.get(url)
    
    # Wait for element to be visible
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a/div/img')))
    
    # Find element by XPath
    xpath_selector = '//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a/div/img'
    elemento_img = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_selector)
    
    # Get 'src' attribute (image URL)
    url_imagen = elemento_img.get_attribute("src")
    
    # Print image URL
    print("URL:", url_imagen)

finally:
    # Quit driver
    if driver:
        driver.quit()
```

After this the waiting time ends.

Comment: Not able to reproduce on my Linux. YOu could also try `//*[@id="content"]//a/div/img` as xpath

Comment: I think it's not related to the selector because it doesn't work for some profiles. If you can, try scraping the profile image from these two creators: https://onlyfans.com/eireenskinnygirl and https://onlyfans.com/mayukoxo,

Comment: Tried the second and worked without issuesñ

Comment: you tried both?